# Syntax error in my sql query: CASE error

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a sql query which, to me, looks good but i get an error. Error is:

> ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'AS region) FROM country as c INNER JOIN
>   country_translation AS t ON c.id = t.cou' at line 1

Query is:

```
query = "SELECT DISTINCT c.id, c.shortname, c.name, (CASE WHEN rt.name is NULL then '' else rt.name" \
                " AS region) " \
                "FROM country as c " \
                "INNER JOIN country_translation AS t ON c.id = t.country_id AND t.locale = '{locale}' " \
                "INNER JOIN region_translation AS rt ON c.region_id = rt.region_id " \
                "AND rt.locale = '{locale}' " \
                "INNER JOIN outlet AS o ON o.billing_country = c.shortname " \
                "INNER JOIN merchant AS m ON o.merchant_id = m.id " \
                "INNER JOIN offer_ent_active AS ofr ON o.merchant_id = m.id " \
                "WHERE m.category = '{category}' "
```

The problem appears to be at the first INNER JOIN. What's wrong here?

Comment: Your `CASE` is missing an `END`

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos I changed the query to look like `"SELECT DISTINCT c.id, c.shortname, c.name, (CASE WHEN rt.name IS NULL THEN '' ELSE rt.name END AS region) "` but I still get the same error

Comment: Try `... END) AS region`, or completely remove parentheses. You don't need them anyway.

Comment: yep, parens were the issue. (Y)

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of `CASE`  statement is

```
  CASE expression
        WHEN condition1 THEN result1
        WHEN condition2 THEN result2
       ...
        WHEN conditionN THEN resultN
        ELSE result
    END
```

In your query the case statement is missing `END`.

```
CASE WHEN rt.name is NULL 
     THEN '' 
     ELSE rt.name
END AS region
```